# How to implement generic TypeScript mapping function that expects return type to match input type and supports spread operators

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a function, that can be used to update multiple entities of various types at once. For now I've tried two versions but one didn't produce TS erros when it should, other produced TS errors when it should not. I've attached one version bellow.

Please take a look at this example. What am I doing wrong?

### What I want to achieve

GOAL: This code should not produce any TypeScript errors.

```
type EntityA = { id: string; createdAt: Date, a: { nested: string; } };
type EntityB = { id: string; createdAt: Date; b: { nested: number; } };

let entitiesA: EntityA[] = [{id: "1", createdAt: new Date(), a: { nested: "abc" }}];
let entitiesB: EntityB[] = [{id: "2", createdAt: new Date(), b: { nested: 123 }}];

const updateAllEntities = (
    updater: <TEntity extends EntityA | EntityB>(entiy: TEntity)=>TEntity
)=>{
    entitiesA = entitiesA.map(entity => updater(entity));
    entitiesB = entitiesB.map(entity => updater(entity));
};

updateAllEntities((entity) => {
    return { 
        ...entity,
        createdAt: new Date()
    };
});

updateAllEntities((entity) => {
    if ("a" in entity) {
        return { ...entity, a: { nested: "abx" } }
    }
    if ("b" in entity) {
        return { ...entity, b: { nested: 123 } }
    }

    throw new Error("Unreachable");
});

updateAllEntities((entity) => {
    return { 
        ...entity,
        // @ts-expect-error wrong type
        a: 123,
        // @ts-expect-error wrong type
        b: 123
    };
});
```

Comment: This is essentially two different things going on, so the question is a bit unfocused (an answer would have to separately explain the issues in each), even though you're trying to solve the same problem in both cases.  Could you narrow it down to one of those and we can focus on it? (more...)

Comment: (...continued)  In short the generic one doesn't work because TS models generic spread as an intersection, which isn't always correct (see [ms/TS#42690](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42690)) and the overload doesn't work because overloads are never properly checked, and arrow function overloads are "overly strict" instead of "overly loose" for function declarations (see [ms/TS#47669](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47669)). Those are really unrelated TS phenomena so please [edit] to focus on one issue and I'd be happy to post an answer.

Comment: Hmm, now you've added a third question.  Right now it's (1) why is are an error in this, (2) why is there an error in this, (3) what other approach could I take to do this (and I'm not 100% sure about this question, since "just don't spread the wrong stuff in for the first approach" would work, but presumably you knew that, so maybe you're asking something else here?)  Could you please pick one of those three so that the question is focused?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the reply, I've updated the question, now it's focused on solution (1 question)

Comment: Given those three pieces of code the solution is to delete the third piece of code and keep the first and *maybe* the second.  If you're asking "how can I keep those two" then you're really still asking all three questions, you're just not saying it.  I've given you the info that ms/TS#42690 is a bug and then ms/TS#47669 is a missing feature, and without one fixed and the other implemented, nothing can prevent someone from writing this problematic code. Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?